# python output incomplete and trailing .0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I try to classify a csv file, but the output value gets trailing .0

```
import pandas as pd

result_1=pd.read_csv('H:\\1\\1.csv',encoding="utf-8",)
SubNetwork_list=list(result_1.groupby(["Phone"]))
for SubNetwork in SubNetwork_list:
 SubNetwork_pd=pd.DataFrame(SubNetwork[1])
 SubNetwork_pd.to_csv("H:\\2\\"+str(SubNetwork[0])+".csv",mode='a', header=False,
                         index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

my csv file

```
ID,name,addr1,addr2,state,ZipCode,Phone
661111154,DAVID,224 Collins Taft Rd,,RI,02830,8142154252
```

The output information is

```
ID,name,addr1,addr2,state,ZipCode,Phone
661111154,DAVID,224 Collins Taft Rd,,RI,2830,8142154252.0
```

Phone values trailing ".0", 0 in Zipcode is missing,
8142154252 → 8142154252.0，
02830 → 2830

How to make numbers display properly

Comment: I have updated my answer that should help please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading the csv file mention the parameter `dtype` as below code

```py
result_1=pd.read_csv('H:\\1\\1.csv',encoding="utf-8",dtype=str)
```

Comment: It won't work if there are null values in Phone

Comment: I have updated the code, see that would help your requirement

Comment: ok it works but it can only format "phone", my csv file still contains a lot of info, other info still contains ".0", how can i format all the columns

Comment: Can you list all the columns you want to format like this in your question above along with their sample data ?

Comment: ok i updated the question, you can check it

Comment: Please add information if your column contains any null values, be as descriptive as possible. Also update the heading of the question per your query.